# Conditional subquery in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query with conditional logic where I only calculate revenue for the most recent records by each month using a datetime column (start_date), but only if there are multiple records in that month from the same account_id.

Here's a basic example of the schema after I join two tables (full schema in sqlfiddle link).

```
| account_id | plan_id | start_date           | plan_interval | price |
|------------|---------|----------------------|---------------|-------|
| 1          | 1       | 2018-01-03T14:52:13Z | month         | 39    |
| 1          | 3       | 2018-02-07T11:10:17Z | year          | 999   |
| 1          | 2       | 2018-02-07T11:11:17Z | month         | 99    |
```

In the above example, I would only like to include rows 1 and 3 in my output, as it's the one record from account_id 1 in January and the most recent of two records for account_id 1 in February.

```
SELECT
MONTH(start_date) AS month,
SUM(CASE WHEN plan_interval = 'month' 
     THEN price * .01 
     ELSE (price * .01)/12 END) AS mrr
FROM subscriptions
  JOIN plans
  ON plans.id = subscriptions.plan_id
WHERE Year(start_date) = 2018 AND 
  CASE WHEN (account_id = account_id
             AND MONTH(start_date) = MONTH(start_date))
             THEN (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM subscriptions)
             ELSE (SELECT start_date FROM subscriptions)
             END
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month ASC;
```

The case statement in the subquery above does not seem to work in doing this. It returns the data without filtering out records when the first condition is met.

Here is an example: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95e6b0/1)

Comment: Your fiddle has subscription data for plan_id 4 but plans does not?

Comment: Yes, feel free to disregard records with plan_id 4 as they are not factored into revenue.

Comment: @Hermes_III . . . I'm a little confused.  You show the schema of one table and have a clear question.  Then you show a query that references multiple tables and has additional logic.  What is the question you want answered?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added clarity to the original question, which involves joining two tables to arrive at the results shown above. The question was how to properly write the subquery in the `WHERE` clause that returns a conditional result if there are multiple records for the same `account_id` in the same month. It's been answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query returns the rows that you are asking for *in the question*:

```
SELECT s.*, p.plan_interval, p.price,
       (CASE WHEN p.plan_interval = 'month' 
             THEN p.price * 0.01 
             ELSE (p.price * 0.01)/12
        END) AS mrr
FROM subscriptions s JOIN
     plans p
     ON p.id = s.plan_id
WHERE YEAR(s.start_date) = 2018 AND 
      s.start_date = (SELECT MAX(s2.start_date)
                      FROM subscriptions s2
                      WHERE s2.account_id = s.account_id AND
                            EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s2.start_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.start_date)
                     )
ORDER BY s.start_date ASC;
```

This uses a subquery to get the most recent record for a subscription for each month.

You can then aggregate this however you wish.

Notes about the query:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The subquery uses the handy `YEAR_MONTH` option of `EXTRACT()`, so it handles both years and months.
- For numeric constants between -1 and 1, I always prepend with a `0`, so `0.12` rather than `.12`.  If find that this makes the decimal point more obvious.

Comment: Thank you! This gave me the result I was looking for. I had tried a similar solution with `s.start_date  =`  in the subquery but using the equal sign as opposed to something like `IN` would only return one result. However, it looks like creating the `s2` table alias is the difference. Why is that?

Comment: @Hermes_III . . . I can't see your query, but this is selecting the maximum date for each account, via the correlation condition in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `WHERE` statement does not work because the `CASE` statement will always return a boolean.

```
  CASE WHEN (account_id = account_id
             AND MONTH(start_date) = MONTH(start_date))
             THEN (SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM subscriptions)
             ELSE (SELECT start_date FROM subscriptions)
             END
```

Another approach to what you are building would involve using a subquery to order the columns the way you want within the groups.

```
SELECT 
  account_id,
  month,
  CASE WHEN plan_interval = 'month' 
     THEN price * .01 
     ELSE (price * .01)/12 
  END AS mrr
FROM (
  SELECT *, MONTH(start_date) AS month
  FROM subscriptions
  INNER JOIN plans ON plans.id = subscriptions.plan_id
  ORDER BY account_id, start_date DESC
) sq
GROUP BY account_id, month
```

This works because selecting columns in a GROUP BY will automatically take the first row that is returned by the subquery for a given group of columns.

Answer (score 0):

First work out the last entry by account and month (sub query a) join to subscriptions to get the plan_id and then get the plan

```
SELECT S.ACCOUNT_id,s.plan_id,s.start_date,p.Price,p.plan_interval,
         case when p.plan_interval = 'month' then p.price * .01 /12 else p.price * .01 end as rev
from subscriptions s
join (select s.account_id,month(s.start_date), max(s.start_date) start_date
        from subscriptions s 
        group by account_id,month(start_date)) a on a.account_id = s.account_id and a.start_date = s.start_date
join plans p on p.id = s.plan_id;


+------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
| ACCOUNT_id | plan_id | start_date          | Price    | plan_interval | rev          |
+------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|          1 |       1 | 2018-01-03 14:52:13 |  3900.00 | month         |   3.25000000 |
|          1 |       2 | 2018-02-07 11:11:17 |  9900.00 | month         |   8.25000000 |
|          2 |       3 | 2018-01-03 17:40:05 | 99900.00 | year          | 999.00000000 |
+------------+---------+---------------------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```