# How to add interval to subscribed date in join table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables transaction,plan so I am getting subscribed users data by joining these two table and at the same time I want to add plan_validity column as interval with subscription date to check whether validity is completed or  not ,but  while adding interval  it is showing error unexpected date_interval near '))' so how to add interval to subscription date of user.

```
transaction table

id    user id  plan_id   subscription_date

1        1       1       2019-06-08    

2        2       3       2019-07-05

plan table

id    plan_validity

1      3 month

2      6  month

3      9 month
```

mysql query:

```
select tr.*,t.subscription_date,DATE_ADD(t.subscription_date, INTERVAL  p.plan_validity) 
from transaction t inner join plan p on t.plan_id=plan.id  where t.user_id=1
```

Comment: Mysql does not do variable substitution so   p.plan_validity is invalid here. Either rewrite your plan table so that it knows the interval as and integer an has a plan_type (monthly annually etc) or use prepared statement for submission to dynamic sql PS the schema mentioned in the fiddle attached to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246968/conditional-subquery-in-where-clause looks better and remarkably similar to what you seem have..

Comment: @P.Salmon  in mysql DATE_ADD('your_date', interval 1 month) we can use this,but I don't know how to use it correctly in join table but this is possible

Comment: Please read my comment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a `CASE` expression that checks the type of interval that you want to add:

```
select t.*,
  case 
    when p.plan_validity like '%month'
      then date_add(t.subscription_date, interval p.plan_validity month)
    when p.plan_validity like '%year'
      then date_add(t.subscription_date, interval p.plan_validity year)      
  end result
from transaction t inner join plan p 
on t.plan_id = p.id  
where t.user_id = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nnntJSN1zfhbf9ny6dK1kh/3).
Results:

```
| id  | user_id | plan_id | subscription_date   | result     |
| --- | ------- | ------- | ------------------- | -----------|
| 1   | 1       | 1       | 2019-06-08          | 2019-09-08 |
```

Comment: thanks it  helped me  but i have question about this why we need to differentiate month year

Comment: Because month and year are keywords that can't be expressed with strings like 'month' and 'year' as you store them. Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add